# Can I place 3D objects on a 2D sprite?

Tags: unity, 2d, 3d-meshes

I am creating a circular island for my game. I will be doing it in Photoshop, and importing it to Unity as a .PNG. Will I be able to place grids and buildings on top of it, like in RTS games, or must my island be a 3D model to do so?

Comment: When showing a sprite in Unity it actually creates a 3D object for you to display it. This is called billboarding, although it is a flat plane (so technically speaking 2D) it is still a object in a 3D world. Even setting unity to 2D it still is a 3D environment with the 3th axis/dimension locked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity allows you to work with both 3D and 2D elements.

To answer your question, yes. You can place a 3D object on top of a 2D sprite. Simply dragging the two objects into a scene, together, will show you this. As per the grid, Unity does not have any such feature built in. We see a grid in the editor, but this grid is not visible in-game. As such, you will be creating the grid, yourself. Assuming you set it up to work, it will work. How you go about doing so is an entirely different question.

[image: An assortment of 3D objects placed on a 2D sprite.]

Alternatively, you could simply use the Terrain tool to make your island, and use the original image as it's texture.